# "python setup.py install" does not create entry points

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I need some help concerning `setuptools`.
My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'vsam = vsam.cmdline:execute',
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

If I run `python setup.py develop`, the specified console script gets properly created. Running `python setup.py sdist` and installing the source distribution with `pip install` also creates the entry point.

But running `python setup.py install` does not create a console script.

Can anyone tell me why?
If anyone needs more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you try `python setup.py install` in a clean virtualenv?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I already tried it, but didn't help.

Comment: What platform are you doing this on?

Comment: I'm running a fedora 21.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading setuptools in the virtualenv, before running `setup.py install`? Could you post the full setup.py? Or link to the project repo if it's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was preventing `setuptools` from creating entry points.
My `MANIFEST.in` file contained the line:

```
prune vsam.egg-info
```

After removing it, everything works fine.